# How to toggle "View replies" button into "Hide replies" on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I used bootstrap button("View x replies") to toggle the visibility of the replies in the comments.It works fine to toggle the content.But I want that if someone click on "View x replies" button the content of the button will be changed into "Hide x replies".After that when user will on "Hide replies" it will change into "View replies" as like as first it is.I used javascript to achieve this.
Here is my code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary d-block" id ="show-{{comment.id}}" type="button" 
  data-toggle="collapse"  data-target="#{{comment.id}}"
  aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" 
  onClick = "myFunction1({{ comment.id }}, {{ comment.get_children.count }} );">
    View {{ comment.get_children.count }} replies
 </button>

<script>
  function myFunction1(comment_id, comment_get_children_count) {
    var id = comment_id;
    var count = comment_get_children_count;

    var x = document.getElementById("show-" + id );
    var y = "View " + count + " replies";
    var z = "Hide " + count + " replies";

    if (x.innerHTML = y){
      x.innerHTML = z;
    }

    // else part is not working
    else {
      x.innerHTML = y;
    }
  }
</script>
```

It works fine when I click **"View x replies"** it changes into **"Hide x replies"**.But next when I click on **"Hide x replies"**, it is not changing into **"View x replies"** what I want.
**So how can I solve this problem?** Any suggetion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **not** checking the condition properly in your `IF` statement.

> `=` is assignment operator VS `==` comparison operator

`=` is an `assignment` operator and to check whether to change `innerHTML`. You need to use `!=` **(Inequality operator)** this to change the `innerHTML` of your button.

[MDN Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Equalityoperators)

**Live Demo:**

```js
function myFunction1(comment_id, comment_get_children_count) {

  var id = comment_id;
  var count = comment_get_children_count;

  var x = document.getElementById("show-" + id);

  var y = "View " + count + " replies";
  var z = "Hide " + count + " replies";


  if (x.innerHTML.trim() != z) {
    x.innerHTML = z;
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = y;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button class="btn btn-primary d-block" id="show-12" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#12" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" onClick="myFunction1(12, 12 );">
  View 12 replies
</button>
```

Comment: Ah! I used assignment op instead of comparison op.Thanks, your solution works for me. :)